# Issue loading Autofac MVC assemblies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac

I'm a bit of a newbie here so forgive the silly question but I'm doing an ASP.NET MVC 5 course and getting different behaviour. Have posted on the training site too and saw sadly the trainer has passed away.

The course calls for me to load a package called Autofac.Mvc5

Then to load that into a class.

```
public class ContainerConfig
{
    internal static void RegisterContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterControllers
    }
}
```

The `builder.RegisterControllers` should allow me to load a `Autofac.Integration.MVC` reference but that's not allowing me.

Instead I get

[image: MVC Error 1]

I definitely have the right assemblies loaded

[image: MVC Assemblies for Autofac]

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Have you installed the "AutoFac.Mvc5" NuGet package? Also check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47431658/autofac-has-downloaded-and-i-have-access-to-the-builder-methods-but-not-the-regi

Comment: Yes the references image came up when I installed it. The course is a couple of years old so he had version 4.0.2 and the current is 6.0.0. I installed the current and then saw the issue above so assumed it might have changed but being a newbie I didn't want to troubleshoot that so uninstalled it and installed 4.0.2 but am still seeing the issue.

Comment: Hey I worked it out sorry newbie error here. I wasn't watching closely enough. There's a Data Namespace and Web component. I clicked on References in the Data Component and installed AutoFac.Mvc5 in there. I think I assumed it was global when you installed packages. Every day's a school day. Sorry for wasting your time.